# Python Sending method name in if clause

Tags: python, if-statement

I have the below piece of code.

```
def create_user():
    print("hello")
def stop_service(): 
    print("world")
    
def retry(operation, attempts):
  for n in range(attempts):
    if operation():
      print("Attempt " + str(n) + " succeeded")
      break
    else:
      print("Attempt " + str(n) + " failed")

retry(create_user, 3)
retry(stop_service, 5)
```

Initially, I didn't have creat_user and stop_service methods defined. To make this code run I added them. But my question is, for what values of operation will it go in the if clause because with the below code it always goes into the else clause. Maybe we don't need methods at all. Just seeing operation() made me guess I need to have create_user and stop_service as methods.
Also if I want to study this, what should I look up for, method calling in Python, or passing method in IF didn't show any results on google.

Comment: Your methods doesn't return `True` or `False`. What use is it with `if`?

Comment: I think you answered my question, it needed to be a boolean for it to show use in if, thanks. Didn't know we could pass method names like this to use.

Comment: Functions are objects. You can pass the function as argument to other functions, the way you did. Look at `lambda; too.

Comment: Both `create_user` and `stop_service` are functions, not methods.  Methods are associated with a class.  In any case, neither of the functions has a `return` statement, so they both implicitly return `None`, which is logically false.  So you should always see the "failed" case.  Change them to return `True` if you want to see the "succeeded" case.

Comment: functions return None by default, so if your function doesnt explicitly return True/False, it will return None. if you check `bool(None)`, it returns `False`. So thats why the if statement wont be read

Comment: you need to look up decorators because that is how proper retry logic is done with Python

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean login in your if statements and run code based off that.

```
def create_user():
    print("hello")
def stop_service(): 
    print("world")
    
def retry(operation, attempts):
    for n in range(attempts):
        print(operation is create_user)
        if operation is create_user:
            create_user()
            print("Attempt " + str(n) + " succeeded")
            break
        elif operation is stop_service:
            stop_service()
            print("Attempt " + str(n) + " failed")

retry(create_user, 5)
retry(stop_service, 5)
```

The print() statement will help you debug for your desired value. 
 Also, I am not sure why do you want to use break in your code but maybe you only uused that for illustration purposes.

 Lastly, you not have to need or have to use methods or create_service or stop_service but maybe you want to use them so you can reuse them. 
Lastly, if you want to learn more about methods, I would suggest you use following links. 
[data-flair.training](https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-method/#:%7E:text=A%20Python%20method%20is%20like,speedup()%2C%20and%20turn().) 
 [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of operation(), If you write:

```
 if operation:
```

the result will be as
Attempt 0 succeeded
Attempt 0 succeeded